# Can you make a map of a fictional country and cities in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am currently working on a project were I am making a fictional country with cities in it. I am wondering if I can do that in QGIS, and if so, how?

I have no experience with any GIS program at all. I just saw QGIS on some forum, and it seemed interesting. The fictional country is based on the Mascarene Plateau in the Indian Ocean. I  want to give the map a more professional look to it and make it look like an actual map, like in an atlas. I have a pretty clear idea on the vegetation and elevation of the landmass, and for the cities, I am still drawing the layout of them.[image: A scan of the landmass I drew]

Comment: Do you have any QGIS (or other GIS) experience? Is this fictional country based on real-world features (e.g. continents on Earth) or is it completely imaginary geometry? What functionality are you looking for beyond "draw the shape of your fictional country"?

Comment: I think you should install the software, and start to work with it.  If you get stuck then let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for every GIS you have first to think about the objects that are located in your city. Does it only contain of streets? Buildings? What about vegetation? Afterwards you have to consider the attributes each of those classes should provide.

This might be a quite complex step, if your target is only on "drawing" a map I would suggest such a drawing tool such as Adobe Illustrator, or even paint. If you plan to make spatial queries against the underlying dataset you should however create a database and make your drawings in a GIS (e.g. QGIS).

So to come to the chase: a GIS is not a drawing-tool, it´s about managing spatial data.

EDIT: There are far more factors that should be taken into account (e.g. the spatial reference system), so I decided to reduce only to the simpliest and most obvious ones.

Comment: They will also need to consider the datum and coordinate system of this fictional land.

Comment: @JamesSLC You´re right, however there are far more factors that should be taken into account, so I decided to reduce only to the simpliest and obvious facts.